# Cannot render const in a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications, gatsby

I'm creating a web app with ReactJS and GatsbyJS and I have some issues with the rendering of const inside my component.

I read the ReactJS official documentation about the map() method and I really don't know what I'm doing wrong.

If anyone can help :

```
const contents = [
    {
        title: "Allier design et performance, c'est possible",
        chapo: "Les meilleures technologies au service de votre site web."
    },
    {
        title: "Nouvel ère : les application web progressives",
        chapo: "Pour des sites web accessibles en tout lieu et tout heure."
    },
    {
        title: "Design centré utilisateur",
        chapo: "Pour un site adapté à votre cible."
    }
]
const contentList = (contents) => contents.map((content, i) =>
    (
        <div className="item" key={i}>
            <div className="headline">
                <h1>{content.title}</h1>
                <h2>{content.chapo}</h2>
            </div>
        </div>)
)
const prevButton = () => {
    return (
        <span>Prev</span>
    )
}
const nextButton = () => {
    return (
        <span>Next</span>
    )
}


export const Teaser = ({prevButton, nextButton, contentList}) => {

    return (
        <section className="teaser">        
            <div className="container">
                {contentList}
            </div>
            <div className="slide-buttons">
                {prevButton}
                {nextButton}
            </div>
        </section>
    )
}
export default Teaser
```

I have **no error message in the console**. However, when I'm exploring the component with React developer tools, I see that my components are not mounted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in `contentList` you are storing the ref of arrow function, you need to call that method to get the result, also you need to pass `contents` array.

Like this:

```
<div className="container">
    {contentList(contents)}
</div>
```

Or write it like this to avoid the method calling:

```
// now contentList will be an array, not a function

const contentList = contents.map((content, i) =>
    (
        <div className="item" key={i}>
            <div className="headline">
                <h1>{content.title}</h1>
                <h2>{content.chapo}</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
)
```

Similarly you need to either remove the arrow function from prev and next button or call them:

```
prevButton()

nextButton()
```

or

```
const prevButton = (
    <span>Prev</span>
)
const nextButton = (
    <span>Next</span>
)
```

Check this snippet, you will get the better idea:

```js
const contentList = (contents) => contents.map((content, i) =>
    (
        <div className="item" key={i}>
            <div className="headline">
                <h1>{content.title}</h1>
                <h2>{content.chapo}</h2>
            </div>
        </div>)
)

console.log('contentList = ', contentList)
```

Comment: Ok, I modified the code and now the part related to  the contentList is displayed but I had to delete the parameters. I cannot render the span dedicated to the buttons

Comment: same, those are also functions, either use `prevButton()` and `nextButton()` or remove the arrow function

Comment: Thank you, I have some trouble with the synthax lmao

Answer (score 1):

I modified the code, and only the part related to the contentList is displayed. Why nextButton and prevButton are not rendered ?

```
import React  from 'react'
import Link from 'gatsby-link'
import './teaser.scss'

const contents = [
    {
        title: "Allier design et performance, c'est possible",
        chapo: "Les meilleures technologies au service de votre site web."
    },
    {
        title: "Nouvel ère : les application web progressives",
        chapo: "Pour des sites web accessibles en tout lieu et tout heure."
    },
    {
        title: "Design centré utilisateur",
        chapo: "Pour un site adapté à votre cible."
    }
]

const contentList = contents.map((content, i) =>
    (
        <div className="item" key={i}>
            <div className="headline">
                <h1>{content.title}</h1>
                <h2>{content.chapo}</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
)

console.log('contentList = ', contentList)
const prevButton = () =>  (
        <p>Prev</p>
    )

console.log('<p> Prev = ', prevButton)
const nextButton = () => (
        <p>Next</p>
    )

console.log('<p> Next = ', nextButton)   

export const Teaser = () => {

    return (
        <section className="teaser">        
            <div className="container">
                {contentList}
            </div>
            <div className="slide-buttons">
                {prevButton}
                {nextButton}
            </div>
        </section>
    )
}
export default Teaser
```

Comment: Because you defined them as functions (ES6 arrow functions), but you aren't invoking the functions in the render, only adding the reference to them. You need to call them as prevButton() and nextButton()